# Operate prefixed expression from input

Tags: c++

I want to operate expression of the following kind without using stacks, only recursion:

`+ - 8 m 4 + 5 7 9`

This should equal `4`, because `−8 + max3(4, 5 + 7, 9)`, being `m` a ternary operator that finds the maximum.
I know how to crack this kind of operations for a simpler expressions, but however trying to adapt my code for this one is giving me wrong outputs.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

int operate() {
    char op;
    cin >> op;
    int val = op - '0';
    if (val < 0) {
        if (op == 'm') return std::max({ operate(), operate(), operate() });
        else if (op == '+') return operate() + operate();
        else return - operate();
    }
    return val;
}

int main() {
    cout << operate() << "\n";
}
```

This outputs `53`, when `4` is expected. Any suggestions on making it work and make it less ugly?
I want the input to be read from `cin`.

Comment: FWIW, `int(op) - '0'` can just be replaced with `op - '0'`.  Anything smaller than an `int` is automatically converted to an `int` in arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Your code doesn't handle unary operators at all it parses the `-` as a binary operator

Comment: @UnholySheep You're right, I updated the OP

Comment: What happens when you try [`m 4 + 5 7 9`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Beta it outputs `61`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your code gets the minus sign `-` it substract eight to the next number, which is `m` (61).

```
int operate() {
    char op;
    cin >> op;
    int val = op - '0';
    std::cout << "Call with " << val << " " << op << std::endl;
    if (val < 0) {
        std::cout << "In if" << std::endl;
        if (op == 'm') {
            std::cout << "in m" << std::endl;
            return std::max({
                    [](){
                        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
                        return operate();}(),
                    [](){
                        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
                        return operate();}(),
                    [](){
                        std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
                        return operate();}() });
        }
        else if (op == '+') {
            std::cout << "in +" << std::endl;
            return [](){
                        std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
                        return operate();}() + [](){
                        std::cout << "5" << std::endl;
                        return operate();}();
        } else {
            std::cout << "in else" << std::endl;
            return - [](){
                        std::cout << "6" << std::endl;
                        return operate();}();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "return " << val << std::endl;
    return val;
}

int main() {
    cout << operate() << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
echo "+ -8 m 4 + 5 7 9" | ./main
Call with -5 +
In if
in +
4
Call with -3 -
In if
in else
6
Call with 8 8
return 8
5
Call with 61 m
return 61
53
```

You shouldn't check `if (val < 0)` but `isdigit()` or `isalpha()` in the `op`.
When  you find `m`, `val` isn't negative, so it simply returns the value when you want to process the `m` operator.

With `if (!::isdigit(op))` the output:

```
Call with -5 +
In if
in +
4
Call with -3 -
In if
in else
6
Call with 8 8
return 8
5
Call with 61 m
In if
in m
1
Call with 4 4
return 4
2
Call with -5 +
In if
in +
4
Call with 5 5
return 5
5
Call with 7 7
return 7
3
Call with 9 9
return 9
4
```

Which is what you expect.

Comment: Well, I see, but this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Norhther, I've completed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions on making it work and make it less ugly?

Here is a working implementation that's a bit neater:

```
#include <iostream>
int op(char c = std::cin.get()) {
  switch (c) {
    case 'm': return std::max({op(), op(), op()});
    case '+': return op() + op();
    case '-': return -op();
    default : return std::isspace(c) ? op() : c - '0';
  }
}
```

As for the code's bug, as Manuel said `val < 0` is not an effective comparison. The ASCII values for `'+'` and `'-'` are less than `'0'`, but `'m'` is not.